ERROR - PostGIS built for PostgreSQL 13.0 cannot be loaded in PostgreSQL 17.2
I tried to install PostGIS independently by downloading it from the PostGIS website using their downloaded postgis-bundle-pg13x64-setup-3.5.0-1.exe.
Problem is that when I attempted to enable the PostGIS on a database using CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
I get this error
ERROR: PostGIS built for PostgreSQL 13.0 cannot be loaded in PostgreSQL 17.2.
Does that mean I need to uninstall and reinstall an older version of PostgreSQL the PostGIS website does say that it is for PostgreSQL 17. does the minor version change cause to be incompatible? Is there a way to set something in PostGIS to get it to try with this newer version of PostgreSQL?

There appears to be a v17 download available: https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg17/ (direct link: https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg17/postgis-bundle-pg17x64-setup-3.5.0-2.exe)

Thanks I couldn't find it on the postgis.net site
